# Problem in RoR testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I reading/learning "agile develpment.." now i'm on Chapter 14 (testing)/

when i tried to run 
"@ruby -I test test/unit/product_test.rb"
i have error that

```
1) Error:
test_invalid_with_empty_attributes(ProductTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "carts" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "carts"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "carts"
```

but cart model isn't belongs to "ActiveRecord"

what i'm doing wrong?

(sorry for mistakes, i'm bad in english)

Comment: What version of the book are you reading? What is the test code? What is the model code? Is this a counter-example of a test that's supposed to fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the database table "carts" does not exist. Rails tests use the 'test' database defined in database.yml. You probably have yet to create the test database, or the database schema may be out of date. Try running `rake db:test:load` or `rake db:test:prepare` to recreate the test database.

You can read more by running `rake --tasks db:test` or checking out [the RubyOnRails.org guide to testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#preparing-your-application-for-testing).